# Swift: Why int! member instance change to int? in block?

Tags: ios, swift

I defined a member instance `frameCount` which type is `Int!`, But when I reference it in block it's type become `Int?`. If I doesn't unwrap it Xcode will prompt complie error "Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?".

I can use it without unwrapping out of block.

```
//Without unwrapping
self.frameCount = self.frameCount + 1
optQueue.async { [weak self] in
    //frameCount become Int?.
    //If I doesn't unwrap it Xcode will prompt complie error "Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"
    self?.frameCount = (self?.frameCount)! + 1;
}
```

Comment: not the frameCount is `Int?`, but `self?.frameCount` is.

Comment: It's not solves your problem, but you should [read this](https://swift.org/blog/iuo/) and restrain from using IUO.

Comment: If `async` is a GCD API `[weak self]` is pointless. GCD dispatch queues don't cause retain cycles. And don't misuse IUO.

Comment: And why not `self?.frameCount += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `self`  is optional not `frameCount` , you can use `guard` to avoid this as you may have a lot of stuff that need to access `self` instead of force-unwrapping them all

```
optQueue.async { [weak self] in
   guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
   strongSelf.frameCount += 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is not optional! Your `self` is. Since you are doing an *asynchronous* call, by the time completion is executed `self` might cease to exist. That is why you are capturing it as `weak`. But if you want it run compulsorily, you could remove the `[weak self]`, but it will hold a strong reference to `self` and prevent it form being deallocated. So if your completion is not called, it'll never get deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can replace `weak self` with `unowned self`, so you will still have a weak reference to self, but not optional one.
However, be careful with that approach, it could lead to a crash if `self` will be deallocated earlier than completion will be executed.

```
optQueue.async { [unowned self] in
    self.frameCount = self.frameCount + 1
}
```